# nuBuilder, Can't add items via Form

Tags: forms, addition

I've searched and searched for this.
Im using nubuilder to make a backoffice. When I try to add something via a form it just refreshes the page but adds no data.

Any idea on the solution?
Thank you

Comment: More details about the problem?

Comment: Well is there anyway i can print out if the query is being made or just giving an error, that would actually be a great help. Also I don't have root user for my cpanel. The database is in MySql and all the nubuilder files are in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the greatest solution but this is what I did for you.
My form had a foreign key to another table, I thought this was the correct solution but removing the foreign key and adding a lookup provides the same basic solution.

Also i Had some discrepancies between the name of the fields and the nubuilder names.